# .NET 6 & EF Core : Add-Migration stuck at using context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, .net-6.0

I am developing a student automation system using EF Core with a code-first approach. There are 4 POCO classes: `User`, `Student`, `Course` and `StudentCourses`. I used partial classes for `DbContext` (`KUSYSDbContext`, `KUSYSDbContext.Student`, `KUSYSDbContext.Course`, `KUSYSDbContext.StudentCourse`).

Once I created my `DbContext`, I can't use `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` (tried with custom migration) since it get stuck at the 'Using Context' phase. My `DbContext` classes are (they are partial classes) in the `KUSYS.Database` project:

```
 public partial class KUSYSDbContext : DbContext
 {
    public KUSYSDbContext(DbContextOptions<KUSYSDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public KUSYSDbContext() : base() { }

    public KUSYSDbContext(string connectionString)
      : base(SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        ConfigureCourseEntities(builder);
        ConfigureStudentEntities(builder);
        ConfigureStudentCoursesEntities(builder);

        builder.Seed();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(builder);
        builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        UpdateSoftDeleteStatuses();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        UpdateSoftDeleteStatuses();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void UpdateSoftDeleteStatuses()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = false;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KUSYS.Student:

```
public partial class KUSYSDbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    private void ConfigureStudentEntities(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureStudentBuilder();
    }
}
```

KUSYS.Course:

```
public partial class KUSYSDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    private void ConfigureCourseEntities(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureCourseBuilder();
    }
}
```

KUSYS.StudentCourses

```
public partial class KUSYSDbContext
{
    public DbSet<StudentCourses> StudentCourses { get; set; }

    private void ConfigureStudentCoursesEntities(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureStudentCoursesBuilder();
    }
}
```

And I have a custom `ModelBuilder` class to handle the fluent API's and seed:

```
public static class KUSYSModelBuilder
{
    public static void ConfigureStudentBuilder(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.Username)
            .IsUnique();


        builder.Entity<Student>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        //Student User relationship
        builder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOne(s => s.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.Student)
            .HasForeignKey<Student>(fk => fk.UserId)
            .HasPrincipalKey<User>(pk => pk.Id);

        //Student Course relationship
        builder.Entity<Student>()
             .HasMany(s => s.Courses)
             .WithOne(o => o.Student)
             .HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id);

        builder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<bool>(m, "IsDeleted") == false);

        builder.Entity<Student>()
        .Property(b => b.IsDeleted)
        .HasDefaultValue(0);
    }

    public static void ConfigureStudentCoursesBuilder(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<StudentCourses>()
            .HasKey(sc => new { sc.StudentId, sc.CourseId });

        builder.Entity<Course>()
             .HasMany(s => s.Students)
             .WithOne(o => o.Course)
             .HasPrincipalKey(o => o.CourseId);

        builder.Entity<StudentCourses>()
            .HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<bool>(m, "IsDeleted") == false);

        builder.Entity<StudentCourses>()
            .Property(b => b.IsDeleted)
            .HasDefaultValue(0);
    }

    public static void ConfigureCourseBuilder(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Course>()
            .HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<bool>(m, "IsDeleted") == false);
    }

    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().
           SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile(@"appsettings.json", false, false)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();


        #region Courses Insertion
        Course c1 = new Course
        {
            CourseId = "CSI101",
            CourseName = "Introduction to Computer Science"
        };
        #endregion

        #region User Insertion
        var salt = _configuration.GetSection("Salt").Value;

        User u1 = new User
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Username = "fethitekyaygil",
            Password = CryptographyHelper.Encode("1q2w3e4r" + salt),
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
            Role = UserRoleEnum.Admin
        };

        #endregion

        #region Student Insertion

        #region Student 1
        Student s1 = new Student
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = "Fethi",
            Lastname = "Tekyaygil",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1996, 6, 7),
            UserId = u1.Id
        };

        StudentCourses s1c1 = new StudentCourses { StudentId = s1.Id, CourseId = c1.CourseId };

        #endregion

        #endregion

        builder.Entity<StudentCourses>().HasData(s1c1);
        builder.Entity<Course>().HasData(c1);
        builder.Entity<User>().HasData(u1);
        builder.Entity<Student>().HasData(s1);
    }
}
```

In `appsettings.json` I have my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MSSQL": {
        "Dev": "Server=abcd.com\\MSSQLSERVER2019;Database=my_db;UserId=my_user;Password=my_pwd;"
    }
}
```

In my ASP.NET Core MVC project (`KUSYS.Web`) in `Program.cs` I'm creating the `DbContext`:

```
string Env = "Dev";
string Database = "MSSQL";    

builder.Services.AddDbContext<KUSYSDbContext>(options =>
{
      options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetSection($"ConnectionStrings:{Database}:{Env}").Value);
      options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
});
```

When I set `KUSYS.Web` (my ASP.NET MVC Core project) as startup project and enter `Add-Migration` command through the Package Manager Console, it gets stuck at "Using Context" phase.

My command:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration -Verbose
```

The output is stuck:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem out. I was using 2 key values in my Course POCO class.

I was using;

```
[Key]
public int Id {get;set;}

[Key]
public string CourseId {get;set;}
```

That caused the problem. After removing the Id column, the problem is solved!